# Node.js Socket.io reconnected namespaced events not coming through

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

So for the following problem, im using socket.io on the node.js server and in the browser.

Ive got a client that makes a connection to a server. Some point down the line a second "connection" is made to a namespace on the same server (in quotes as the connection is actually multiplexed so there is actually only one connection).

This second "connection" is like a subscribe to a feed type thing so i use `second_connection_socket.on('event', function_name);` ... but later i want to disconnect from this feed so i do `second_connection_socket.removeListener('event', function_name);` which works fine but the data is still being sent to the browser for this second connection.

I then try and do `second_connection_socket.disconnect();` which works (as the data is no longer sent to the browser) but when i try and connect again to the namespace using the `io()` call and resubscribe to the events, nothing happens. The original connection is still open but its not receiving the requested namespaced events.

Is this a bug with the io client or should i be making another call?

Comment: at the moment I've resorted to actually opening a second websocket connection which i don't really want to do but it seems to have temporarily fixed the problem.

Comment: Ok the problem is to do with the io library i think, if you do socket.disconnect(); you can't just open it again by doing io('same_as_before') when you have multiplex = true